What does that Groovy constructor like call mean?
Person person = new Person(name: "Fred", age: 42)

What does that Groovy syntax mean ?
Is this a call to init a Person constructor ?  What if Person class has another attribute
address and occupation. Will Person(name: "Fred", age: 42) still work ?
Is there a dokumentation on this ?

http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#xform-MapConstructor

thanks. When I write Spock Tests I don't set @MapConstructor in the Java Code but still I can set like that:  new Person(name: "Fred", age: 42)

@Toni26, without map constructor - it will call the default constructor and will set corresponding parameter values

ok. But let's say default constructor of Person has 4 Parameter and I only give 2 parameter like here : new Person(name: "Fred", age: 42)

Let's assume you have this class:
class Person {
  String name
  int age
  String phoneNumber = "none"
  int areaCode = 0
}

If you create a person like:
Person person = new Person(name: "Fred", age: 42)
println person.phoneNumber // will be "none"
println person.areaCode // will be 0

If you create a person like:
Person person = new Person(phoneNumber: "1-222-333-444", areaCode: 10)
println person.name // will be null (not empty, as no default value exists)
println person.age // will be 0 (as int is primitive data type)

In summary, any field that you don't specify, will have its default value.
